# How to show that $u(t,x)\in C([0,T],H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

If $u(t,x)\in L^{2}([0,T],H^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$, $\partial_{t}u \in  L^{2}([0,T],L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$, prove that
$$
u(t,x)\in C([0,T],H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))
$$

Comment: Do you have a PDE that $u$ satisfies? Evans' PDE book has results of this kind.

Comment: just to be precise, you find the theorem you are looking for on page 288 (Evans, Partial Differential Equation), theorem 4 for a general non negative integer $m$.